# Sony xperia acro s InputMismatchException when java.util.Scanner.nextFloat()

Tags: java, android

I have a string: "100 0 2 3.0 100 420 5.0 280 420"

And in code I do:

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(walls).useDelimiter(" ");
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        int type = s.nextInt();
        int rotation = s.nextInt();             
            int actionsCount = s.nextInt();
            float s1 = s.nextFloat(); --> crash on Sony
    }
```

On Smsung Galaxy SII (2.3.6) and Motorolla Xoom (4.1.2) all works fine. Why can be this error on Sony XPERIA Acrto s wirh Android 4.0.4?

```
03-01 11:05:42.436: E/AndroidRuntime(21019): java.util.InputMismatchException
03-01 11:05:42.436: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1012)
03-01 11:05:42.436: E/AndroidRuntime(21019):    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:1297)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Locale. On Sony was Locale.RU, where real digits writes with comma, like this: 
"100 0 2 3,0 100 420 5,0 280 420"

So fix is in using US locale.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(walls).useDelimiter(" ");
 s.useLocale(Locale.US);  --> need add this string
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        int type = s.nextInt();
        int rotation = s.nextInt();             
            int actionsCount = s.nextInt();
            float s1 = s.nextFloat(); --> And NO crash on Sony
    }
```